# Comparing two groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have two groups - one group which was presented with one picture of a politician with his wife, one group where the politician was alone. Participants in each group also answered questions (as a Likert-scale item) on how likely they were to vote for that politician.

I need to compare how likely each group was to vote for that politician, and compare.

Which would be the best statistical test to use?

Comment: What form does their response take? An estimate of a probability ("I'd be 60% likely to vote for him")? Some ordered categorical scale, like a Likert-scale item (e.g. "Not at all", "Probably not", ..., "Definitely")? A binary variable ("Would"/"Would not")?

Comment: Their responses were on a Likert scale.

Answer (score 3):

If the number of observations is reasonably large and the distribution of responses not too jammed up one end or the other, a plain two-sample t-test may be reasonable, especially if you would be prepared to add such an item to similar Likert-scale items to produce a scale, were additional items available (this illustrates preparedness to assume that the scale-intervals are equispaced).

It is possible to take a nonparametric approach such as with a Mann-Whitney/Wilcoxon but the heavy ties make this approach only about as good as the $t$ in many cases.

A more easily justified approach might be to deal with the ordered categorical response more directly, and look at a regression model that deal with it (where there's a dummy to signify membership of the second group), such as say proportional odds models, cumulative logit ("grouped-continuous") models, continuation-ratio models, polytomous logistic models, adjacent-category logistic models or stereotype logistic models.