# Which statistical analysis to use? Stata

Tags: anova, stata

So I've got this database that had people rank how much they like very light red, light red, red, dark red and very dark red cars (scale 0-10). My professor says that because it is an 11-point numerical scale we can treat the data as continuous.

Which test should I use in stata to determine whether people like lighter red cars better than darker red cars?

Comment: That seems to be just one variable, the rankings for however many people were surveyed.

Comment: See this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60904/comparing-two-groups ?